# How to open a email shareable app in flutter web application?

Tags: flutter

I tried using share_plus and url_launcher packages but they are not working. Please let me know is there any way by which I can open a shareable apps to send a email via flutter web application with subject and body prepopulated. It is working fine with share_plus in android and ios but it is not working in chrome browser in web.